# Piping into less and editing: "cannot edit standard input" error. Workarounds?

Tags: emacs, less

I recently learned that if I page my files with `less`, I can press `v` and open the buffer in Emacs. This works as long as I have the environment variable `$EDITOR` set up correctly, which in my case I have it as:

```
export EDITOR='env TERM=xterm-256color emacs -nw'
```

The above gives me the ability to load emacs within the terminal that runs `less`.

However, the trick above does not work when **piping** commands to `less`. When doing this, `less` complains with the following message:

```
Cannot edit standard input (press RETURN)
```

My question is, why does this happen? But most importantly, **is there any workaround to it**?

Comment: You should learn how to use [emacsclient](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Emacs-Server.html), which will let you edit files in an already-running copy of Emacs.  Emacs isn't the fastest-starting editor.

Comment: Why did you rollback my edit?  Isn't the title supposed to be a question?

Comment: Sorry @John, I didn't see your edit. I edited the title to clarify that I am mostly interested in workarounds to this problem. I think the title as it is: `Piping into less and editing: “cannot edit standard input” error. Workarounds?` is clear. Why do think otherwise?

Comment: That's understandable. Although I would assume that if you're asking why you got the error, it should be obvious that you would want a workaround.

Comment: I agree, although the most voted answer so far addresses the `why` only, and not the `workarounds`, so I added the emphasis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it was already said, you cannot edit an input stream.

The workaround is quite obvious: **save the stream to a file from within `less` and open the saved file**. To do that while viewing, press **`s`** and give a name of a file. Then either exit `less` and open the file by hand, or, still from within `less`, type **`:e`** and give the name of the file you just saved.

Answer (score 26):

A good workaround is to pipe the output from less to your editor, e.g. after "echo foo | less" you can do:

```
g|$vim -
```

`g` will jump to the first line of the file/input, `|` will invoke the "pipe" action, `$` is the mark ("the end"), followed by the command to pipe the range into (`vim -` in this case, where the "-" means to read the input from stdin).

Comment: Awesome, thanks!

Comment: That's awesome! Is there a way to bind that to a key in `less`?

Answer (score 5):

It means exactly what it said - you can only edit a file that is on the disk in this way (from `less`). If you piped the output of a process, its `STDOUT` is going into `STDIN` for `less`; there is no file to edit.