# Can I use the mouse to properly select text in less?

Tags: terminal, less

I've just discovered that I can add the following lines to `~/.vimrc`.

```
set mouse=a
:vmap <C-C> "+y
```

This has the effect of being able to select text with the mouse (i.e. in visual mode), and then copy the actual text to the X clipboard with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. This differs from the default copy from the terminal, as it's the real text I'm copying, not what the terminal sees. For example, if there were tabs in the text, then previously I'd copy them as spaces.

Is there a way to make less behave the same way? i.e. can I copy verbatim what is in the text file I'm viewing in less?

Comment: Have you tried with gpm?

Comment: @YoMismo No. I'm not really sure how that would help, as the terminal emulator would still contain literal spaces instead of tabs, in the above example.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were working in the console, not an X terminal :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Not a task for less

No,
I do not think you can do that directly, because less does not have a cursor to begin with.
It would need one to navigate to start and end of the text to select.
`less` is just not the right tool for character-level navigation.

### Tabs already expanded

You can use the key <kbd>shift</kbd> and the mouse to make a selection; This is handled by the terminal, not by less. But the terminal does not know how spaces and tabs where arranged - less does the interpretation of tabs internally, and writes only normal " " characters to the screen.

There are tools like `screen`, `tmux`  and `byobu`, which can do lots of impressive things in this area.
I did not check, but I assume that these terminal multiplexers do not have a way around that - being terminals, in the end - and will behave the same.

### Use vim

If you are showing a file in `less`, there is a nice solution:
Press the key <kbd>v</kbd> in `less` to open the current file in `vim` - asuming your `$EDITOR` etc. is set up for `vim`.

This does not work when showing stdin from a pipeline or so, although there are [workarounds](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43460/18887).

### Mouse scrolling, at least

But you can at least scroll with the mouse wheel:

That seems even to be enabled by default, but the mouse wheel events get suppressed by a different option.

For a quick test, try:

```
LESS=-r man less
```

The option `-X` (`--no-init`) blocks scrolling - check what your environment variable `LESS` contains:

```
$ echo $LESS
```

The option `-q` (`--quiet`, `--silent`) also causes trouble, according to [SU: How to make mouse wheel scroll the less pager using bash and gnome-terminal?](https://superuser.com/questions/455212/how-to-make-mouse-wheel-scroll-the-less-pager-using-bash-and-gnome-terminal)

Comment: Great answer. The `v` key is fantastic! (I've taken the liberty of a cool workaround to get it working in pipelines too.) FWIW in my terminal emulator (terminator) I don't have to hold shift when I select text.

Comment: @Sparhawk Hey, the workaround is at least as fantastic!

Comment: In addition, there is a pager called `vimpager` which you can use to replace `less` whole-sale. It actually just uses `vim` wrapped in a small script.

Comment: @HalosGhost Thanks for that. `vimpager` looks pretty cool, but I did have [issues with yanking](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager/issues/45) that makes me prefer using less and `v`.

Comment: @Sparhawk Technically, you could compare the vimrc used, or use parts of your normal vimrc for `vimpager` until it works; (I try hard to not activate all my `vim` plugins when starting `vimpager`...)

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Part of the issue is that the improvements that `vimpager` gives to me over `less` are not large enough for me to pursue it too much. In some cases, I prefer the behaviour of `less` as a pager, such as keeping overstrike in man pages, and not being able to scroll past the last line.

Answer (score 3):

You can copy the top line displayed in `less` to the X11 CLIPBOARD selection by typing with `less`:

```
|.head -n1|xclip -sel c<Enter><Enter>
```

That pipes the less buffer from the top line to the `.` mark (so in effect the whole screen content) to the `head -n1|xclip -sel c` command (to store the first line of that in the CLIPBOARD selection)

You could configure your terminal emulator to paste that string upon a given key-press, or bind that to a key or key combination in `less` key bindings. For instance, to bind it on <kbd>Alt+C</kbd>:

```
printf '%s\n' '#commands' '\ec pipe .head -n1|xclip -sel c\n' | lesskey -
```

However note, you'll to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> after that to acknowledge the "|done (press RETURN)" prompt.

With `xterm`, you could also define a new selection mode for instance here when holding <kbd>Ctrl+Alt</kbd> when extending the selection that tells `less` which lines to copy from its current screen:

Write  a `lesspaste` script like:

```
#! /bin/sh -
start=${1%%";"*}
end=${1#*" "}
end=${end%";"*}
head -n "$((end))" | tail -n "$((end - start + 1))" | xclip -sel c
```

And define xterm translation tables (here on the command-line for testing, but you'll want to add that to a X resource file):

```
xterm -xrm 'XTerm.VT100.translations: #override \
  Meta Ctrl<Btn1Down>: select-start()\n\
  Meta Ctrl<Btn1Motion>: select-extend()\n\
  Meta Ctrl<Btn1Up>: select-end(SECONDARY) \
    insert-formatted("|.lesspaste '\''%P %p'\''\n\n", SECONDARY)'
```

You'd then mark the lines to paste by dragging the mouse with <kbd>Ctrl+Alt</kbd> held, and upon releasing the Button 1, xterm would tell less to pipe the current screen to our `lesspaste` script with the start and end coordinates passed as one argument (`y1;x1 y2;x2`).

(note that it may not work properly if `less` is invoked with `-s` to squeeze blank lines (as is typical when invoked by `man`), as the input that is fed to `lesspaste` will *not* have its blank lines squeezed (so the line number offsets may be wrong)).

Comment: @Sparhawk, see edit.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for me. Nothing new is in the clipboard. Is `less` supposed to give any kind of feedback? `j` doesn't appear to do anything for me.

Comment: @Sparhawk, do you have any custom key-bindings for `less`, `j` scrolls down by one line (`forw-line`) in the default key binding (actually `J` (`forw-line-force`) would be better here, I'll edit). `|` should give you some feedback. (prompt for the mark, and then the command to enter).

Comment: No, I didn't, but I was testing with text that was less than a page long, so perhaps that's why `j` did nothing. The first option now works (+1). The second option seems fairly complicated with a few caveats, so I didn't try it. I think `v` is good enough for me.