# How to change/fix the v command in less using a shell profile?

Tags: bash, shell-script, emacs, bashrc

I am beginning to learn bash and emacs and wanted to change my default editor from vi to emacs. After going through many great questions throughout different stackexchange communities, I have not figured it out and apparently have (hopefully only temporarily) messed up my `v` command when using `less`. Now when I press `v` while reading a file in `less`, instead of opening vi (the default) or emacs (what I'd like), it does nothing; i.e. it stays in `less`, as far as I can tell, and I cannot edit any text. Fortunately I can still exit using `q` and I don't notice anything else acting up.

## What I did and when things changed:

I am using the terminal emulator provided with mac osX, but I do have XQuartz downloaded. Using homebrew cask I installed emacs.

A lot of questions on stackexchange did a great job explaining the `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL` variables that can be set in my .bash_profile. Since my macbook comes with an older version of emacs already installed, I made sure to use the current version of emacs installed by homebrew.

Since I'm just beginning to learn all of this stuff, I couldn't determine the best way of setting everything up. Here is how I currently have it in my .bash_profile:

```
# changing emacs from the default osX version to the version obtained from homebrew                 
alias emacs="/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/25.2/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs"
alias enw="emacs -nw"

# setting emacs as the editor in term instead of vi                                                
EDITOR="enw";export EDITOR
VISUAL="enw";export VISUAL
```

After adding the above code to my .bash_profile nothing significant (that I could tell) changed. I used `echo` to verify that the `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL` variables were correctly changed.

When I would use `less` to read a file, I could still type `v`, but my terminal would use vi to edit the file instead of the desired emacs. So I tried changing how I defined `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL`, e.g. by using the full path as in my `alias emacs=...` with the `-nw` flag instead of `enw`. And I also tried removing the quotations. None of this did anything different that I could tell.

Unfortunately since I'm just starting out and I do not have any concrete tasks to work on I'm just messing around with basic commands and files, which is why I have been using the `less` command. Currently I am not familiar with any other way of using the `$EDITOR` variable while in the terminal. So I'm not sure if my issue only pertains to `v` or if it is an issue with `$EDITOR`.

Eventually I saw some questions relating to this where it was recommended to add `ALTERNATE_EDITOR="";export ALTERNATE_EDITOR` and so I tried that out without really understanding why. Also no discernible difference with the `v` command in `less`.

After some more searching I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23304/piping-into-less-and-editing-cannot-edit-standard-input-error-workarounds/23329?newreg=d5c2998c65184dd39ea0063f15e4bf66) question, which seems like the closest to my original plan (although I wasn't trying to pipe anything as I understand it; and I do not understand what 'paging' is unfortunately). So I changed `$EDITOR="enw"` to `$EDITOR="env TERM=xterm-256color enw"` and this was roughly when `v` stopped doing anything while reading a file with `less`.

Before doing the last code addition, I checked what `$TERM` normally is, which was already `xterm-256color` for me. Now I am not saying this is what messed up my `v` command, it's just the timeline where `v` stopped invoking vi while in `less`. I changed everything back to the very first code that I tried, but `v` still won't work for me.

(Sorry this is so long, just trying to explain the process in case it helps!) Now, if I comment out my `$EDITOR` additions to my .bash_profile everything goes back to normal, which is good I guess. So I can use `v` in `less` as long as I am not using `$EDITOR` and `$VISUAL` in my .bash_profile. However I *want* to have these changed and so this is where my dilemma is. This is probably a trivial question, but I would greatly appreciate any advice or insight.

PS- While trying to trouble shoot this issue I came across `emacsclient` and I can use that command, but I don't understand why I should use that instead of my `enw`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliases are only "active" in the current shell session. `less` will not be able to invoke an alias through `$EDITOR` or `$VISUAL` (and no other process except from possibly the shell itself would either).

Instead, set e.g. `VISUAL` to

```
export VISUAL='/usr/local/Cellar/emacs/25.2/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs -nw'
```

or install `emacs` in a standard location accessible through your `$PATH`, either by compiling it yourself, or using something like HomeBrew, MacPorts, or Fink, and then simply use `export VISUAL='emacs -nw'`.

Comment: I swear that I tried this but clearly I messed it up somewhere. I just did exactly as you recommended and it works perfectly now, thank you very much! And thanks for explaining the part about aliases only being active in the shell, I was unaware of this.